# Using a local instance of DynamoDB with Amazon Kinesis KCL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

Is there any way to store the checkpoints / lease table on locally hosted DynamoDB? I don't see any way in KCL config to specify the connection, AWS docs also don't help. I would like to avoid forking the KCL code.

If that matters, I'm using KCLPy with Python.